# AC/DC power supply module with 20mA output current

Tags: ac, dc, 4-20ma

i want get 20mA current with 24V ac to dc. 
I have found this power supply module with 6-9A output current but i need max 20mA. What can i add with this module to achieve my settings?

I am powering medical tool so output current must be max 20mA because sometimes the patient have to touch so
If i wamt to be safe it must be max 20mA constant output current.

[image]

Product description - 
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you are powering. Do you want constant 24 V (constant voltage) or constant 20 mA (constant current). And where is the 24 V AC coming from?

Comment: Please read [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/6334) and if you still have questions, come back and edit this post to clarify what you need to know.

Comment: I see you have the 4-20mA current loop for something like industrial controls. Your selected approach is not a good starting place for either a sensor/transducer or a receiver.

Comment: 150mV ripple may need a filter then you may have CM noise issues. What is this for?

Comment: why do you need to use that particular module? .... it is surely an overkill

Comment: Do yourself a favor and just buy a supply that already has the necessary medical approvals. Here is a 10W 24V @ 420mA supply for 20 bucks... https://www.astrodynetdi.com/ecatalog/power-supplies/ASM-0105

Answer (score 6):

> I am powering medical tool so output current must be max 20 mA because sometimes the patient have to touch so If i wamt (sic) to be safe it must be max 20mA.

No, for medical devices you don't use cheap power-supplies like this. The risk of harm is too great. Judging by the nature of your question you are not qualified to carry out this work.

Comment: You cant judge this topic i need the solution. The device will be controlled by experts before production.

Comment: @Nikayout Why not ask the experts for advice?

Comment: @Nikayout If they are experts and they see you use this in a medical application, they will reject it. Don’t even start down that road.